# Jquery being imported but AJAX not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension to auto login into the wifi, I use AJAX to do the post request but when I check the network of the pop it no POST request is sent instead, it just shows the popup files being loaded, and a jquery-1.10.1.min.map GET failed.
Here is my popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BCA Auto Login</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: #2c3e50;
        }
        label{
            color:#f1c40f;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" id="form">
            <label>Enter username
                <input id="username">
            </label>
            <br>
            <label>Enter password
                <input id="password" type="password">
            </label>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "BCA Auto Login",
  "description": "This extension automatically signs you into the BCA wifi",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js","login.js"],
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

And here is my login.js:

```
$('#form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = 'https://ccahack.bergen.org/auth/perfigo_validate.jsp';
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://whatsmywork.appspot.com/auth/perfigo_validate.jsp',
        data : {
            reqFrom: 'perfigo_simple_login.jsp',
            uri: 'https://ccahack.bergen.org/',
            cm: 'ws32vklm',
            userip: 'IP',
            os: 'MAC_OSX',
            index: '4',
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            provider: 'fds',
            login_submt: 'Continue'
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: why don't you use <input type="button"  /> instead submit?

Comment: Maybe something to do with same-origin policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to attach the event before the document is ready. Enclose the code in your **login.js** between `$(function() {` and `});`